# CSS .target attribute pointing to svg element

Tags: html, css, svg

Update: Sorry for the confusion; a silly grammar error (.target) instead of (:target) caused my problem and confusion. 
With :target all works as expected.

I have an inline svg in `page.html` 
that I want to modify with an external stylesheet.
Let us assume the svg just consists of

```
<svg>
  <rect id="DA" 
    style="stroke-width:0.75;fill:#0000FF;"
    width="50" height="50" x="10" y="10">
  </rect>
</svg>
```

The following line in the css file fills the rectangle as expected:

```
#DA {fill:#00FFFF !important;  }
```

However, I would like the rectangle to be filled only if I open the page as `page.html#DA`. I would have hoped that

```
#DA.target {fill:#00FFFF !important; }
```

should do the trick; however the line doesn't seem to be applied, even if the page is loaded as `page.html#DA`.

**Question**: How can I make css attributes apply to svg elements depending on the target link?

*Context*: I would like to provide an svg floorplan, where you can click on a link in the address book entry of a person to get to the floorplan with the corresponding room highlighted (without creating a different webpage for each room).

**Update**:
As (probably?) requested in a comment, here is the complete example. The following is the file `page.html` :

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">#DA.target {fill:blue !important; }</style>
</head>
<body>
<svg>
  <rect id="DA" 
    style="stroke-width:0.75;fill:red;"
    width="50" height="50" x="10" y="10">
  </rect>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is as follows:

- When I open `page.html` I get a red rectangle, as expected.
- When I delete `.target` from the code, I get a blue one, as expected.
- But with the `.target` in place, I still get the red rectangle even if I open the page as `page.html#DA`. I would have hoped for a blue one.

Comment: Please provide svg and picture of what you want please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the right syntax of target in CSS :

```
#DA:target {fill:blue !important;}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no class(target) in your svg tag, you have to correct your CSS selector

```
#DA:target {
    fill:#00FFFF !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it if you are ok with using some jQuery.

```js
// ADD CLASS
$(".roomList").on("mouseenter",function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  $("#"+id).attr("class", "highlight");
});

// REMOVE CLASS
$(".roomList").on("mouseout",function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");  
  $("#"+id).attr("class", "highlight clearHighlight");
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  fill: #00ff00;
  color: red;
}

.clearHighlight {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 14.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 43363)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="レイヤー_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
  y="0px" width="280px" height="184px" viewBox="0 0 280 184" enable-background="new 0 0 280 184" xml:space="preserve">
<rect x="31.833" y="26.885" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" width="230.334" height="129.115"/>
<rect id="roomA" x="39.803" y="33.261" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" width="44.632" height="37.459"/>
<rect id="roomB" x="91.608" y="33.261" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" width="44.632" height="37.459"/>
<rect id="roomC" x="145.406" y="33.261" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" width="44.632" height="37.459"/>
<rect id="roomD" x="198.806" y="33.261" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" width="44.632" height="37.459"/>
<rect id="roomE" x="39.803" y="106.984" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" width="44.632" height="37.459"/>
<rect id="roomF" x="91.608" y="106.984" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" width="44.632" height="37.459"/>
<rect id="roomG" x="145.406" y="106.984" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" width="44.632" height="37.459"/>
<rect id="roomH" x="198.806" y="106.984" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" width="44.632" height="37.459"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 58.9814 54.6021)" font-family="'KozGoPro-Regular-90ms-RKSJ-H'" font-size="9.5641">A</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 110.7866 54.6021)" font-family="'KozGoPro-Regular-90ms-RKSJ-H'" font-size="9.5641">B</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 166.3115 54.6021)" font-family="'KozGoPro-Regular-90ms-RKSJ-H'" font-size="9.5641">C</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 219.1797 54.6021)" font-family="'KozGoPro-Regular-90ms-RKSJ-H'" font-size="9.5641">D</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 58.9814 129.2549)" font-family="'KozGoPro-Regular-90ms-RKSJ-H'" font-size="9.5641">E</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 110.7866 129.2549)" font-family="'KozGoPro-Regular-90ms-RKSJ-H'" font-size="9.5641">F</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 166.3115 129.2549)" font-family="'KozGoPro-Regular-90ms-RKSJ-H'" font-size="9.5641">G</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 217.5859 129.2549)" font-family="'KozGoPro-Regular-90ms-RKSJ-H'" font-size="9.5641">H</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 33.1611 23.9634)" font-family="'KozGoPro-Regular-90ms-RKSJ-H'" font-size="9.5641">FloorPlan</text>
</svg>

<br>
<span id="room1" data-id="roomA" class='roomList'>RoomA</span><br>
<span id="room2" data-id="roomB" class='roomList'>RoomB</span><br>
<span id="room3" data-id="roomC" class='roomList'>RoomC</span><br>
<span id="room4" data-id="roomD" class='roomList'>RoomD</span><br>
<span id="room5" data-id="roomE" class='roomList'>RoomE</span><br>
<span id="room6" data-id="roomF" class='roomList'>RoomF</span><br>
<span id="room7" data-id="roomG" class='roomList'>RoomG</span><br>
<span id="room8" data-id="roomH" class='roomList'>RoomH</span><br>
<span id="room9" data-id="roomI" class='roomList'>RoomI</span><br>
```